# Confused about big O of n^2 vs 2^n

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

I read in a book that the following expression `O(2^n + n^100)` will be reduced to: `O(2^n)` when we drop the insignificant parts. I am confused because as per my understanding if the value of `n` is `3` then the part `n^100` seems to have a higher count of executions. What am I missing?

Comment: *"if the value of n is 3"* - well there's your problem. Big O is about **large values of n**.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Big O notation is asymptotic in nature, that means we consider the expression as n tends to infinity.

You are right that for n = 3, `n^100` is greater than `2^n` but once n > 1000, `2^n` is always greater than `n^100` so we can disregard `n^100` in `O(2^n + n^100)` for n much greater than 1000.

For a formal mathematical description of Big O notation the wikipedia article does a good job

For a less mathematical description this answer also does a good job:

[What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation?rq=1)

Comment: "as n tends to some very large number." *to infinity

Comment: Best way to get a sense of this is to look at graph of `2^n` and `n^100`

Answer (score 4):

The big O notation is used to describe asymptotic complexity. The word asymptotic plays a significant role. Asymptotic basically means that your `n` is not gonna be `3` or some other integer. You should think of `n` being infinitely large.

Even though `n^100` grows faster in the beginning, there will be a point where `2^n` will outgrow `n^100`.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the fact that `O(n)` is the asymptotic complexity. Speaking more strictly, you could calculate `lim(2^n / n^100)` when `n -> infinity` and you will see it equals to infinity, so it means that asymptotically `2^n` grows faster than `n^100`.

Answer (score 2):

When complexity is measured with n you should consider all possible values of n and not just 1 example. so in most cases, n is bigger than 100. this is why n^100 is insignificant.